# counting frequency of a word in xquery

Tags: xquery

the xml file

```
    <teiHeader>
        <fileDesc>
            <titleStmt>
                <title>  Oxford City Council Health and Environmental Protection Committee meeting. Sample containing about 11223 words speech recorded in public context </title>
                <respStmt>
                    <resp> Data capture and transcription </resp>
                    <name> Oxford University Press </name>
                </respStmt>
            </titleStmt>
            <editionStmt>
                <edition>BNC XML Edition, December 2006</edition>
            </editionStmt>
            <extent> 11223 tokens; 11688 w-units; 482 s-units </extent>
            <publicationStmt>
                <distributor>Distributed under licence by Oxford University Computing Services on behalf of the BNC Consortium.</distributor>
                <availability> This material is protected by international copyright laws and may not be copied or redistributed in any way. Consult the BNC Web Site at http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk for full licencing and distribution conditions.</availability>
                <idno type="bnc">KS0</idno>
                <idno type="old"> OCCEnv </idno>
            </publicationStmt>
            <sourceDesc>
                <recordingStmt>
                    <recording n="139401" type="DAT"/>
                </recordingStmt>
            </sourceDesc>
        </fileDesc>
        <encodingDesc>
            <tagsDecl>
                <namespace name="">
                    <tagUsage gi="align" occurs="69"/>
                    <tagUsage gi="c" occurs="1408"/>
                    <tagUsage gi="div" occurs="1"/>
                    <tagUsage gi="event" occurs="3"/>
                    <tagUsage gi="mw" occurs="110"/>
                    <tagUsage gi="pause" occurs="2"/>
                    <tagUsage gi="s" occurs="482"/>
                    <tagUsage gi="u" occurs="192"/>
                    <tagUsage gi="unclear" occurs="65"/>
                    <tagUsage gi="vocal" occurs="7"/>
                    <tagUsage gi="w" occurs="11688"/>
                </namespace>
            </tagsDecl>
        </encodingDesc>
        <profileDesc>
            <creation date="0000">0000-00-00 Origination/creation date not known </creation>
            <particDesc n="C872">
                <person ageGroup="X" xml:id="PS6H7" role="unspecified" sex="f" soc="AB" dialect="NONE" educ="X">
                    <persName>Chair</persName>
                </person>
                <person ageGroup="X" xml:id="PS6H8" role="unspecified" sex="m" soc="UU" dialect="NONE" educ="X">
                    <persName>g</persName>
                </person>
                <person ageGroup="X" xml:id="PS6H9" role="unspecified" sex="f" soc="UU" dialect="NONE" educ="X">
                    <persName>chair2</persName>
                </person>
                <person ageGroup="X" xml:id="PS6HA" role="unspecified" sex="m" soc="UU" dialect="NONE" educ="X">
                    <persName>i</persName>
                </person>
                <person ageGroup="X" xml:id="PS6HB" role="unspecified" sex="m" soc="UU" dialect="NONE" educ="X">
                    <persName>h</persName>
                </person>
                <person ageGroup="X" xml:id="PS6HC" role="unspecified" sex="m" soc="UU" dialect="NONE" educ="X">
                    <persName>foe</persName>
                </person>
                <person ageGroup="X" xml:id="PS6HD" role="unspecified" sex="f" soc="UU" dialect="NONE" educ="X">
                    <persName>b</persName>
                </person>
                <person ageGroup="X" xml:id="PS6HE" role="unspecified" sex="m" soc="UU" dialect="NONE" educ="X">
                    <persName>a</persName>
                </person>
                <person ageGroup="X" xml:id="PS6HF" role="unspecified" sex="f" soc="UU" dialect="NONE" educ="X">
                    <persName>ei</persName>
                </person>
                <person ageGroup="X" xml:id="PS6HG" role="unspecified" sex="m" soc="UU" dialect="NONE" educ="X">
                    <persName>bp</persName>
                </person>
                <person ageGroup="X" xml:id="PS6HH" role="unspecified" sex="m" soc="UU" dialect="NONE" educ="X">
                    <persName>c</persName>
                </person>
                <person ageGroup="X" xml:id="PS6HJ" role="unspecified" sex="m" soc="UU" dialect="NONE" educ="X">
                    <persName>d</persName>
                </person>
                <person ageGroup="X" xml:id="PS6HK" role="unspecified" sex="f" soc="UU" dialect="NONE" educ="X">
                    <persName>e</persName>
                </person>
                <person ageGroup="X" xml:id="PS6HL" role="unspecified" sex="u" soc="UU" dialect="NONE" educ="X">
                    <persName>d</persName>
                </person>
            </particDesc>
            <settingDesc>
                <setting n="OCCEnv" who="PS6H7 PS6H8 PS6H9 PS6HA PS6HB PS6HC PS6HD PS6HE PS6HF PS6HG PS6HH PS6HJ PS6HK PS6HL">
                    <placeName>Oxfordshire:  Oxford </placeName>
                    <activity> Council Committee Meeting </activity>
                </setting>
            </settingDesc>
            <textClass>
                <catRef targets="SPO ALLTIM3 ALLAVA0 ALLTYP2 SCGDOM3 SPOLOG2 SPOREG1"/>
                <classCode scheme="DLEE">S meeting</classCode>
                <keywords>
                    <term> (none) </term>
                </keywords>
            </textClass>
        </profileDesc>
        <revisionDesc>
            <change date="2006-10-21" who="#OUCS">Tag usage updated for BNC-XML</change>
            <change date="2000-12-13" who="#OUCS">Last check for BNC World first release</change>
            <change date="2000-09-06" who="#OUCS">Redo tagusage tables</change>
            <change date="2000-09-01" who="#OUCS">Check all tagcounts</change>
            <change date="2000-06-23" who="#OUCS">Resequenced s-units and added headers</change>
            <change date="2000-01-29" who="#OUCS">Revised participant details</change>
            <change date="2000-01-21" who="#OUCS">Added date info</change>
            <change date="2000-01-09" who="#OUCS">Updated all catrefs</change>
            <change date="2000-01-09" who="#OUCS">Updated REC elements to include tape number</change>
            <change date="2000-01-08" who="#OUCS">Updated titles</change>
            <change date="1999-12-25" who="#OUCS">corrected tagUsage</change>
            <change date="1999-09-21" who="#UCREL">POS codes revised for BNC-2; header updated</change>
            <change date="1994-11-27" who="#dominic">Initial accession to corpus</change>
        </revisionDesc>
    </teiHeader>
    <stext type="OTHERSP">
        <div>
            <!--
Oxford City Council: Health and Environmental Protection Committee (Nuclear Issues and Pollution Control) Sub-Committee.
Wednesday, 18th April 1990, 2.30pm, Town Hall.-->
            <u who="PS6H7">
                <s n="3">
                    <w c5="AV0" hw="well" pos="ADV">Well</w>
                    <c c5="PUN">, </c>
                    <w c5="AJ0" hw="good" pos="ADJ">good </w>
                    <w c5="NN1" hw="afternoon" pos="SUBST">afternoon</w>
                    <c c5="PUN">, </c>
                    <w c5="PNI" hw="everybody" pos="PRON">everybody</w>
                    <c c5="PUN">, </c>
                    <w c5="PNP" hw="i" pos="PRON">I </w>
                    <w c5="VVB" hw="think" pos="VERB">think </w>
                    <w c5="PNP" hw="we" pos="PRON">we</w>
                    <w c5="VHD" hw="have" pos="VERB">'d </w>
                    <w c5="AV0" hw="well" pos="ADV">better </w>
                    <w c5="VVI" hw="get" pos="VERB">get </w>
                    <w c5="VVN" hw="start" pos="VERB">started</w>
                    <c c5="PUN">.</c>
                </s>
                <s n="4">
                    <w c5="PNP" hw="we" pos="PRON">We </w>
                    <w c5="VVD" hw="look" pos="VERB">looked </w>
                    <w c5="AV0" hw="so" pos="ADV">so </w>
                    <w c5="AJ0" hw="thin" pos="ADJ">thin </w>
                    <w c5="PRP" hw="on" pos="PREP">on </w>
                    <w c5="AT0" hw="the" pos="ART">the </w>
                    <w c5="NN1" hw="ground" pos="SUBST">ground</w>
                    <c c5="PUN">, </c>
                    <w c5="PNP" hw="i" pos="PRON">I </w>
                    <w c5="VVD" hw="think" pos="VERB">thought </w>
                    <w c5="PNP" hw="we" pos="PRON">we</w>
                    <w c5="VM0" hw="would" pos="VERB">'d </w>
                    <w c5="VVI" hw="sit" pos="VERB">sit </w>
                    <w c5="CJC" hw="and" pos="CONJ">and </w>
                    <w c5="VVI" hw="wait" pos="VERB">wait </w>
                    <w c5="CJC" hw="and" pos="CONJ">and </w>
                    <w c5="VVI" hw="see" pos="VERB">see </w>
                    <w c5="CJS" hw="if" pos="CONJ">if </w>
                    <w c5="PNI" hw="everyone" pos="PRON">everyone</w>
                    <w c5="VBZ" hw="be" pos="VERB">'s </w>
                    <w c5="VVG-AJ0" hw="come" pos="VERB">coming</w>
                    <c c5="PUN">, </c>
                    <w c5="CJC" hw="but" pos="CONJ">but </w>
                    <w c5="UNC" hw="erm" pos="UNC">erm </w>
                    <w c5="PNP" hw="we" pos="PRON">we</w>
                    <w c5="VM0" hw="will" pos="VERB">'ll </w>
                    <w c5="VHI" hw="have" pos="VERB">have </w>
                    <w c5="TO0" hw="to" pos="PREP">to </w>
                    <w c5="VVI" hw="get" pos="VERB">get </w>
                    <w c5="VVN" hw="start" pos="VERB">started </w>
                    <w c5="AV0" hw="anyway" pos="ADV">anyway</w>
                    <c c5="PUN">.</c>
                </s>
                <s n="5">
                    <w c5="PNP" hw="we" pos="PRON">We</w>
                    <w c5="VM0" hw="will" pos="VERB">'ll </w>
                    <w c5="VVI" hw="welcome" pos="VERB">welcome</w>
                    <c c5="PUN">, </c>
                    <w c5="PNP" hw="we" pos="PRON">we </w>
                    <w c5="VHB" hw="have" pos="VERB">have </w>
                    <w c5="CRD" hw="two" pos="ADJ">two </w>
                    <w c5="NN2" hw="speaker" pos="SUBST">speakers</w>
                    <c c5="PUN">, </c>
                    <w c5="NP0" hw="mr" pos="SUBST">Mr </w>
                    <w c5="NP0" hw="bob" pos="SUBST">Bob </w>
                    <w c5="NP0" hw="plumtree" pos="SUBST">Plumtree</w>
                    <c c5="PUN">, </c>
                    <w c5="CJC" hw="and" pos="CONJ">and </w>
                    <w c5="NP0" hw="ms" pos="SUBST">Ms </w>
                    <w c5="NP0" hw="erica" pos="SUBST">Erica </w>
                    <w c5="NP0" hw="ison" pos="SUBST">Ison</w>
                    <c c5="PUN">.</c>
                </s>
                <s n="6">
                    <w c5="PNP" hw="we" pos="PRON">We </w>
                    <w c5="VVD" hw="ask" pos="VERB">asked </w>
                    <w c5="PNP" hw="they" pos="PRON">them </w>
                    <w c5="PRP" hw="to" pos="PREP">to </w>
                    <w c5="AT0" hw="the" pos="ART">the </w>
                    <w c5="NN1" hw="meeting" pos="SUBST">meeting </w>
                    <w c5="CJC" hw="and" pos="CONJ">and </w>
                    <w c5="PNP" hw="we" pos="PRON">we </w>
                    <w c5="VVB" hw="look" pos="VERB">look </w>
                    <w c5="AV0" hw="forward" pos="ADV">forward </w>
                    <w c5="PRP" hw="to" pos="PREP">to </w>
                    <w c5="VVG-NN1" hw="listen" pos="VERB">listening </w>
                    <w c5="PRP" hw="to" pos="PREP">to </w>
                    <w c5="PNP" hw="you" pos="PRON">you </w>
                    <w c5="AV0" hw="later" pos="ADV">later </w>
                    <w c5="AVP" hw="on" pos="ADV">on </w>
                    <w c5="PRP" hw="in" pos="PREP">in </w>
                    <w c5="AT0" hw="the" pos="ART">the </w>
                    <w c5="NN1" hw="agenda" pos="SUBST">agenda</w>
                    <c c5="PUN">.</c>
                </s>
                <s n="7">
                    <w c5="AT0" hw="the" pos="ART">The </w>
                    <w c5="NN2" hw="minute" pos="SUBST">minutes </w>
                    <w c5="PRF" hw="of" pos="PREP">of </w>
                    <w c5="AT0" hw="the" pos="ART">the </w>
                    <w c5="NN1" hw="meeting" pos="SUBST">meeting </w>
                    <w c5="VVD-VVN" hw="hold" pos="VERB">held </w>
                    <w c5="PRP" hw="in" pos="PREP">in </w>
                    <w c5="NP0" hw="january" pos="SUBST">January</w>
                    <c c5="PUN">.</c>
                </s>
                <s n="8">
                    <w c5="DT0" hw="any" pos="ADJ">Any </w>
                    <w c5="NN2" hw="correction" pos="SUBST">corrections </w>
                    <w c5="PRP" hw="to" pos="PREP">to </w>
                    <w c5="AT0" hw="the" pos="ART">the </w>
                    <w c5="NN2" hw="minute" pos="SUBST">minutes </w>
                    <w c5="ORD" hw="first" pos="ADJ">first</w>
                    <c c5="PUN">?</c>
                </s>
                <s n="9">
                    <w c5="NN1-VVB" hw="page" pos="SUBST">Page </w>
                    <w c5="CRD" hw="1" pos="ADJ">1</w>
                    <c c5="PUN">?</c>
                </s>
                <s n="10">
                    <w c5="NN1" hw="page" pos="SUBST">Page </w>
                    <w c5="CRD" hw="2" pos="ADJ">2</w>
                    <c c5="PUN">?</c>
                </s>
                <s n="11">
                    <w c5="NN1" hw="page" pos="SUBST">Page </w>
                    <w c5="CRD" hw="3" pos="ADJ">3</w>
                    <c c5="PUN">?</c>
                </s>
            </u>
            <u who="PS6H8">
                <s n="12">
                    <w c5="ITJ" hw="yes" pos="INTERJ">Yes</w>
                    <c c5="PUN">, </c>
                    <w c5="NP0" hw="judith" pos="SUBST">Judith </w>
                    <w c5="NP0-NN1" hw="gaffan" pos="SUBST">Gaffan </w>
                    <w c5="PNP" hw="i" pos="PRON">I </w>
                    <w c5="VVB" hw="believe" pos="VERB">believe</w>
                    <c c5="PUN">, </c>
                    <w c5="UNC" hw="erm" pos="UNC">erm </w>
                    <w c5="XX0" hw="not" pos="ADV">not </w>
                    <w c5="NP0" hw="judith" pos="SUBST">Judith </w>
                    <w c5="NP0-NN1" hw="gaffon" pos="SUBST">Gaffon</w>
                    <c c5="PUN">, </c>
                    <w c5="DTQ" hw="whatever" pos="PRON">whatever </w>
                    <w c5="DT0" hw="that" pos="ADJ">that </w>
                    <w c5="VVD" hw="mean" pos="VERB">meant</w>
                    <c c5="PUN">, </c>
                    <w c5="PNP" hw="it" pos="PRON">it</w>
                    <w c5="VBZ" hw="be" pos="VERB">'s </w>
                    <align with="KS0LC002"/>
                </s>
            </u>
            
            <u who="PS6H8">
                <s n="483">
                    <w c5="EX0" hw="there" pos="PRON">There </w>
                    <w c5="VBZ" hw="be" pos="VERB">is </w>
                    <w c5="AT0" hw="a" pos="ART">a </w>
                    <w c5="NN1" hw="school" pos="SUBST">school </w>
                    <w c5="PRP" hw="in" pos="PREP">in </w>
                    <w c5="NP0" hw="ferry" pos="SUBST">Ferry </w>
                    <w c5="NP0" hw="hinksey" pos="SUBST">Hinksey </w>
                    <w c5="NP0" hw="road" pos="SUBST">Road </w>
                    <w c5="VBZ" hw="be" pos="VERB">is</w>
                    <w c5="XX0" hw="not" pos="ADV">n't </w>
                    <w c5="EX0" hw="there" pos="PRON">there</w>
                    <c c5="PUN">, </c>
                    <w c5="AT0" hw="a" pos="ART">a </w>
                    <w c5="AJ0" hw="middle" pos="ADJ">middle </w>
                    <w c5="NN1" hw="school" pos="SUBST">school </w>
                    <w c5="PNP" hw="i" pos="PRON">I </w>
                    <w c5="VVB" hw="think" pos="VERB">think</w>
                    <c c5="PUN">, </c>
                    <w c5="AV0" hw="so" pos="ADV">so </w>
                    <w c5="DT0" hw="that" pos="ADJ">that</w>
                    <w c5="VBZ" hw="be" pos="VERB">'s </w>
                    <w c5="AT0" hw="the" pos="ART">the </w>
                    <w c5="AJ0" hw="only" pos="ADJ">only </w>
                    <w c5="PNI" hw="one" pos="PRON">one </w>
                    <w c5="PNP" hw="i" pos="PRON">I </w>
                    <w c5="VVB" hw="know" pos="VERB">know</w>
                    <c c5="PUN">.</c>
                </s>
                <s n="484">
                    <w c5="AT0" hw="the" pos="ART">The </w>
                    <w c5="NN1" hw="thing" pos="SUBST">thing </w>
                    <w c5="PNP" hw="i" pos="PRON">I</w>
                    <w c5="VM0" hw="would" pos="VERB">'d </w>
                    <w c5="AV0" hw="really" pos="ADV">really </w>
                    <w c5="VVI" hw="like" pos="VERB">like </w>
                    <w c5="VBZ" hw="be" pos="VERB">is </w>
                    <w c5="AT0" hw="a" pos="ART">a </w>
                    <w c5="NN1" hw="glossary" pos="SUBST">glossary </w>
                    <w c5="PRF" hw="of" pos="PREP">of </w>
                    <w c5="NN2" hw="term" pos="SUBST">terms</w>
                    <c c5="PUN">.</c>
                </s>
            </u>
        </div>
    </stext>
</bncDoc>
```

the xquery file

```
let $file := doc("C:/Users/money/Desktop/xml/files/KS0.xml")/bncDoc/stext/div/u/s/w
return 
  for $value in distinct-values(for $node in $file  where $node[text()] = "has"  return normalize-space(lower-case($node/following-sibling::node()[1])))
  let $count := count(for $node in $file  where $node[text()] = "has"  return normalize-space(lower-case($node/following-sibling::node()[1])) eq $value)
  return concat($value, " ", $count)
```

the above code produces output

- large 26
- been 26
- gone 26
- done 26
- a 26
- 26
- intentions 26
- just 26
- got 26
- to 26
- now 26
- in 26
- tropical 26
- since 26
- dare 26

in the output above 26 is wrong value

26 are the number of time we had match on condition where node text is "has"
after distinct we get 17 results which are ok but 26 (frequency is wrong)

output should be

- large 1
- been 2
- gone 1
- done 1
- a 6
  etc

Comment: Please show us a minimal XML input sample and explain the XML input structure. Also state which XQuery processor and/or XQuery version you use as it sounds grouping is the easier approach.

Comment: Hi Martin please check I've added sample xml file

Comment: Does that sample give the result you show? And which XSLT processor and XSLT version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following is what you want (you haven't really explained what you are trying to achieve):

```
declare variable $search-term as xs:string external := 'has';

let $words := doc("C:/Users/money/Desktop/xml/files/KS0.xml")/bncDoc/stext/div/u/s/w
return 
  for $word in $words[normalize-space() = $search-term]
  group by $sibling := normalize-space($word/following-sibling::w[1])
  return $sibling || ' ' || count($word)
```